# How to show data fetched by database in gridview?

Tags: android

I want to show data(image and text) in grid view by fetching it from database.I amm trying to first insert the data in database table and try to fetch the data from database and to show it in gridview.

This is my main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private RelativeLayout rl;

        private Tab TabOrder;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

            ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
            actionbar.setTitle("Select To Order");
            actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            TabOrder = actionbar.newTab().setText("ORDER");


            Fragment FragmentOrder = new FragmentOrder();

            TabOrder.setTabListener(new MyTablistenerClass(FragmentOrder));

            actionbar.addTab(TabOrder);

        }

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public class FragmentOrder extends Fragment{


            private Context context;
            private int layoutResourceId;
            private ArrayList<Category> data;
            ArrayList<Category> imageArry = new ArrayList<Category>();
            OrderAdapter adapter;
            private ArrayList<Category> categories;


            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griddeal, null);




                DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(MainActivity.this);
                // get image from drawable
    //          Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    //                  R.drawable.car);
    //
    //          // convert bitmap to byte
    //          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //          image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    //          byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                /**
                 * CRUD Operations
                 * */
                // Inserting Contacts
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");


                Category c1 = new Category();
                c1.setCategorydescription("vegetables");


                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.car);

                // convert bitmap to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                db.insertCategoriesDetail(c1);
                //db.insertCategoriesDetail(new Category("Vegetables", imageInByte));
                // display main List view bcard and contact name

                // Reading all contacts from database
                List<Category> categories = db.getCategoriesDetail();
                for (Category cn : categories) {
                    String log = "ID:" + cn.getId() + " Name: " + cn.getCategorydescription()
                            + " ,Image: " + cn.getCategoryimage();

                    // Writing Contacts to log
                    Log.d("Result: ", log);
                    //add contacts data in arrayList
                    imageArry.add(cn);

                }
                adapter = new  OrderAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.griddealitems,
                        imageArry);
                GridView dataList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridDeal);
                dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

                dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                return view;
            }
        }

        public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category>{
              Context context;
                int layoutResourceId;   
               // BcardImage data[] = null;
                ArrayList<Category> data=new ArrayList<Category>();

                public OrderAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Category> data) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
                    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
                    this.context = context;
                    this.data = data;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View row = convertView;
                    ImageHolder holder = null;

                    if(row == null)
                    {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                        holder = new ImageHolder();
                        holder.grid_deal_text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.grid_deal_text);
                        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.grid_deal_image);
                        row.setTag(holder);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
                    }

                    Category picture = data.get(position);
                    holder.grid_deal_text.setText(picture.categorydescription);
                    //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

                    byte[] outImage=picture.categoryimage;
                    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
                    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
                   return row;

                }

                public class ImageHolder
                {
                    ImageView imgIcon;
                    TextView grid_deal_text;
                }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }



        public class MyTablistenerClass implements android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

            Fragment fragment1;

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public MyTablistenerClass(Fragment fragment){
                this.fragment1 = fragment;
            }


            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                FragmentTransaction fragMentTra;


                    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                    actionBar.show();
                    actionBar.setTitle("Select Category");

                    //actionBar.setIcon(R.id.search);
                    FragmentOrder Fram2 = new FragmentOrder();
                    //fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), Fram2);
                    fragMentTra.commit();


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }

        }

    }
```

This my databaseManager class:

```
    public class DatabaseManager {

        private Context context = null;
        private SQLiteDatabase database=null;
        private DatabaseHelper dbHelper=null;


        public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        public void open() throws SQLException {
            if (dbHelper==null) {
                dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            }
            if (database==null) {
                database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
        }

        public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
            database = null;
            dbHelper = null;       
        }   

        public long insertCategoriesDetail(Category categorydetail){

            long result = 0;

            try{

                if (database==null) {
                    open();
                }
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORYDESCRIPTION, categorydetail.getCategorydescription());
                values.put(DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORYIMAGE, categorydetail.getCategoryimage());

                result = database.insert(DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME_CATEGORY, null, values);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Res : " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(context, "crashed" + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            return result;

        }   


        public List<Category> getCategoriesDetail() {

            if (database==null) {
                open();
            }

            List<Category> categoriesdetailsList = new ArrayList<Category>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME_CATEGORY;

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Category detailList = new Category();

                    detailList.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    detailList.setCategorydescription(cursor.getString(1));

                    detailList.setCategoryimage(cursor.getBlob(2));

                    categoriesdetailsList.add(detailList);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            close();
            return categoriesdetailsList;
        }   

    }
```

Logcat:

```
11-15 16:57:39.127: E/AndroidRuntime(703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 16:57:39.127: E/AndroidRuntime(703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.orderdatabase/com.example.orderdatabase.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 16:57:39.127: E/AndroidRuntime(703):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
```

Whatever I am doing is not working.I am getting nullpointerexception.
Please anybody tell me where i m wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: updated my question with logcat..

Comment: Its NPE man.. try to find out some object which is not initialized...

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your problem by using Example that is given below.

```
public List<UserInfo> getUerInfoDetails() {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
          db=getReadableDatabase();

          List<UserInfo> userInfoList=new ArrayList<UserInfo>();

          // Select All Query
          String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mainToDo";

          Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

          // looping through all rows and adding to list
          while(cursor.moveToNext())
          {
              UserInfo obj=new UserInfo();

            obj.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            obj.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            userInfoList.add(obj);

          }
                   close();

         return userInfoList;
      }
```